# How to find the column-wise unique elements, and their frequencies, of a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Currently, I am finding the column-wise unique elements, and their frequency, of a 2d array using pandas:

```
#Dummy array 
arr = [[0,-1,0,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,0,-1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,-1]]

#Convert to pandas
pd_arr = pd.DataFrame(arr)

#Apply value_counts on each column
val_counts = pd_arr.apply(pd.value_counts)
```

This results in the dataframe:

[image: example_result]

Which is exactly what I want - here, the index represents the unique values and the table is populated with the frequency of these values in each of the 7 columns within the dummy array.

In reality, arr is 40x8 and contains -1, 1 and 0 values - this isn't big, but sits within a loop of several hundred thousand. The entire loop is taking too long, so I am searching for quicker methods for each part.

After a long time searching, I can't seem to find a way to do this without using pandas. Finding a solution using numpy arrays instead of converting to pandas is possibly ideal, as directly using numpy makes other parts of my loop much much faster and switching between pandas and numpy doesn't sound very clean and tidy either. However, I am open to faster pandas options too!

I have attempted solutions on arr using things like np.unique `np.unique(arr)`

However this, and my unsuccessful attempts at manipulating this, just gives the unique values `array([-1,  0,  1])` and the total frequencies for the whole array, with no flexibility to do it across axes like in the example output above.

There doesn't seem to be much else addressing this particular problem, however please direct me to them if I am wrong!

In reality, arr is 40x8 and contains -1, 1 and 0 values - I know this isn't big, but it sits within a loop of several hundred thousand so the time it takes adds up!

I'd love to hear your suggestions on how to find these unique values and their counts! I am not limited in what modules I can use. Thanks :)

Comment: `pd_arr.transform(pd.value_counts)` also get's you the same result. Check if it helps with timing.

Comment: What does "sitting in a loop of several hundred thousand" mean exactly? Can you make a dataset of shape `(40, 8, several hundred thousand)`, or are you looking to process each iteration individually?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will check timings using transform.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mean that I am running the loop 600,000 times and this is just one part of the loop, so I am looking to process it individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking advantage of there only being three values -1,0,1 you can use the following code which takes 23 us (a >500x speedup over the pandas method) for a 40x8 array on my pretty average laptop:

```
def count_it(a):
    total = a.shape[0]
    non_0 = np.count_nonzero(a,axis=0)
    delta = a.sum(0)
    return np.array([(non_0-delta)>>1,total-non_0,(non_0+delta)>>1])
```

This returns actual counts, if you want nan to indicate a count of 0 you have to replace 0s with nans.

Example:

```
a = np.random.randint(-1,2,(40,8)) 

count_it(a)
# array([[12, 12,  8, 12, 14, 12, 16, 12],
#        [15, 11, 20, 17, 11, 11, 11, 14],
#        [13, 17, 12, 11, 15, 17, 13, 14]])

# check against pandas:
np.all(pd.DataFrame(a).apply(pd.value_counts) == count_it(a))
# True
```

How it works:

Let us consider a single column C and let m,z,p be the counts of -1s 0s and 1s. Then

1. m+z+p = len(C)
2. m+p = np.count_nonzero(C)
3. p-m = C.sum()

We can---and the code does---solve this for m,z and p.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I see what you are doing and I think it will help massively! Just trying to figure out the error 'ufunc 'right_shift' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'' ' and I will accept your answer. I think this is an issue on my end, though!

Comment: Quick question, is there any way of knowing if any of the -1,0,1 values do not appear at all in any of the columns? I.e. right now I get an array of 3 rows and 8 columns, if I just get a result of 2 rows and 8 columns, is there a way of knowing which value didn't appear?

Comment: @SophieMayne You can replace the right shift by one (">>1") with division by 2 ("//2" or "/2" or "*0.5"). A missing value will result in a count of 0 look for 0s and you will know whicih values did not occcur. There will always be three rows.